# How to apply video effects (filters like sepia, vintage, etc.) on TextureView in android?

Tags: android, filter, textureview, video-effects

How can we apply filters like sepia, vintage, etc. to a video, and consequently post the same on our servers?

Likewise, we can bluff user by creating a filter layer on TextureView, and consequently applying the corresponding filter on the server.

CODE :

```
package com.example.mediaplayerdemo_video;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.SurfaceTexture;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Surface;
import android.view.TextureView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TextureView.SurfaceTextureListener {

    // Log tag.
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getName();

    // Asset video file name.
    private static final String FILE_NAME = "test.mp4";

    // MediaPlayer instance to control playback of video file.
    private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initView();
    }

    private void initView() {
        TextureView textureView = (TextureView) findViewById(R.id.textureView);
        textureView.setSurfaceTextureListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mMediaPlayer.stop();
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureAvailable(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i2) {
        Surface surface = new Surface(surfaceTexture);

        try {
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd(FILE_NAME);
            mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
            mMediaPlayer.setSurface(surface);
            mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();

            // Play video when the media source is ready for playback.
            mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                    mediaPlayer.start();
                }
            });

        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureSizeChanged(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture, int i, int i2) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSurfaceTextureDestroyed(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceTextureUpdated(SurfaceTexture surfaceTexture) {
    }

}
```

Comment: You can see some real-time camera filters applied to camera input with a GLES shader in Grafika's "show + capture camera" activity (https://github.com/google/grafika).  Old demo video here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kH9kCP2T5Gg .  Since you can play to a SurfaceTexture, you can do something similar if you play to a standalone SurfaceTexture and then render that to the TextureView.

Comment: @Sarkar I suggest you take a look at this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31958741/1118886)