# Android: Dynamically Blur Surface with Video

Tags: android, surfaceview, exoplayer

I am building an Android application where an ExoPlayer plays a video onto the surface of a SurfaceView, and I am investigating whether it is possible to dynamically blur the playing video.

Blurring techniques that involve first generating a bitmap of the view to blur will not work, since the surface part of a SurfaceView does not appear in bitmaps.

Surfaces and views used to have built-in blurring effects in older versions of Android (e.g. Surface.FX_SURFACE_BLUR), but seem to have been deprecated in newer APIs.

Can anyone share some insight on how a surface can be dynamically blurred? Thank you.

Comment: Use a TextureView https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/98 and then look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633424/how-to-apply-video-effects-filters-like-sepia-vintage-etc-on-textureview-in

Comment: I see. I am unclear though as to why you recommend a TextureView as opposed to a SurfaceView. Does it make a difference?

Comment: Since you are trying to apply a filter (blur effect) I think you'll need its SurfaceTexture - I recommend reviewing http://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html and the Show+Capture Camera app of the Grafika project: https://github.com/google/grafika

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are lots of questions on StackOverflow with small bits and pieces of what needs to be done. I'll go over the method I used and hopefully it will be useful to somebody.

If this was a static blur of a video frame, it would be sufficient to play the video in a `TextureView`, use the `.getBitmap()` function and blur the resulting Bitmap using a tool such as Renderscript. However, `.getBitmap()` is performed on the main UI thread, and hence lags the video whose frames it is trying to copy.

To perform a blur for every frame, the best approach seems to be to use a GLSurfaceView with a custom renderer. I used the code available in [VidEffects](https://github.com/krazykira/VidEffects) pointed to from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31805837/applying-effects-on-video-being-played) as a good starting point.

Blurs with large radii can be very computationally intensive. That is why I first approached performing the blur with two separate fragment shaders (one to blur horizontally, and one to blur the result vertically). I actually ended up using only one fragment shader to apply a 7x7 Gaussian kernel. A very important thing to keep in mind if your `GLSurfaceView` is large is to call `setFixedSize()` on the `GLSurfaceView`'s `SurfaceHolder` to make its resolution lower than that of the screen. The result does not look very pixelated since it is blurred anyway, but the performance increase is very significant.

The blur I made managed to play 24fps on most devices, with `setFixedSize()` specifying its resolution to be 100x70.

Answer (score 7):

In case anyone wants a single pass fragment shader to complete the circle... The following code implements the `ShaderInterface` defined in the code available from [VidEffects](https://github.com/krazykira/VidEffects).  I adapted it from [this example on ShaderToy.com](https://www.shadertoy.com/view/XdfGDH).

```
public class BlurEffect2 implements ShaderInterface {

    private final int mMaskSize;
    private final int mWidth;
    private final int mHeight;

    public BlurEffect2(int maskSize, int width, int height) {
        mMaskSize = maskSize;
        mWidth = width;
        mHeight = height;
    }

    @Override
    public String getShader(GLSurfaceView mGlSurfaceView) {

        float hStep = 1.0f / mWidth;
        float vStep = 1.0f / mHeight;

        return  "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n" +          
                "precision mediump float;\n" +
                //"in" attributes from our vertex shader
                "varying vec2 vTextureCoord;\n" +

                //declare uniforms
                "uniform samplerExternalOES sTexture;\n" +

                "float normpdf(in float x, in float sigma) {\n" +
                "    return 0.39894 * exp(-0.5 * x * x / (sigma * sigma)) / sigma;\n" +
                "}\n" +


                "void main() {\n" +
                "    vec3 c = texture2D(sTexture, vTextureCoord).rgb;\n" +

                //declare stuff
                "    const int mSize = " + mMaskSize + ";\n" +
                "    const int kSize = (mSize - 1) / 2;\n" +
                "    float kernel[ mSize];\n" +
                "    vec3 final_colour = vec3(0.0);\n" +

                //create the 1-D kernel
                "    float sigma = 7.0;\n" +
                "    float Z = 0.0;\n" +
                "    for (int j = 0; j <= kSize; ++j) {\n" +
                "        kernel[kSize + j] = kernel[kSize - j] = normpdf(float(j), sigma);\n" +
                "    }\n" +

                //get the normalization factor (as the gaussian has been clamped)
                "    for (int j = 0; j < mSize; ++j) {\n" +
                "        Z += kernel[j];\n" +
                "    }\n" +

                //read out the texels
                "    for (int i = -kSize; i <= kSize; ++i) {\n" +
                "        for (int j = -kSize; j <= kSize; ++j) {\n" +
                "            final_colour += kernel[kSize + j] * kernel[kSize + i] * texture2D(sTexture, (vTextureCoord.xy + vec2(float(i)*" + hStep + ", float(j)*" + vStep + "))).rgb;\n" +
                "        }\n" +
                "    }\n" +

                "    gl_FragColor = vec4(final_colour / (Z * Z), 1.0);\n" +
                "}";
    }

}
```

Just as Michael has pointed out above, you can increase the performance by setting the size of the `SurfaceView` using `setFixedSize`.

```
@BindView(R.id.video_snap)
VideoSurfaceView mVideoView;

@Override
public void showVideo(String cachedPath) {
    mImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    mVideoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    //Get width and height of the video
    final MediaMetadataRetriever mRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    mRetriever.setDataSource(cachedPath);
    int width = Integer.parseInt(mRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_WIDTH));
    int height = Integer.parseInt(mRetriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_HEIGHT));

    //divide the width and height by 10
    width /= 10;
    height /= 10;

    //set the size of the surface to play on to 1/10 the width and height
    mVideoView.getHolder().setFixedSize(width, height);

    //Set up the media player
    mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    mMediaPlayer.setLooping(true);

    try {
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(cachedPath);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Timber.e(e, e.getMessage());
    }

    //init and start the video player with the mask size set to 17
    mVideoView.init(mMediaPlayer, new BlurEffect2(17, width, height));
    mVideoView.onResume();
}
```

Comment: i can't thank you enough for this! really saved my bacon :D